# Quiero hacer esta app pero no se cual es la mejor opción para organizar y ubicar los botones para que se adapten a todas las pantallas

Tags: javascript, android-layout, diseño, layout

Quiero hacer esta app pero no se cual es la mejor opción para organizar y ubicar los botones para que se adapten a todas las pantallas, tengo una imagen de fondo sin los botones, tengo el diseño de los botones redondos estos van desde un xlm, que irán encima del fondo, solo necesito ayuda con este diseño para que los botones siempre se adapten a cualquier tamaño de pantalla a acorde con la imagen de fondo, Intente de varias formas y el mejor diseño que hice fue con linear layout, y pues quedo como el código que adjunto.

Este es el Activity que tengo hasta el momento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

IMAGEN DE FONDO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SonA"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="A"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SonC"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
            android:text="C"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/click_colora"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/click_colora">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/click_colora">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/click_colora">
            </Button>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/click_colora">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/click_colora">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/click_colora">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/click_colora"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">
            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SonB"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="B"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SonD"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Juan, específicamente, cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Cual es la mejor opción para este diseño, para que se me adacte a todas las pantallas, si le tocará hacer esta app a usted como lo aria??

Comment: Juan, recuerda que las preguntas basadas en opiniones se deben evitar en este sitio, y muy probablemente terminan cerradas. Por favor, échale una mirada a [cuáles preguntas debo evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio.